# Custom keyboard shortcuts on iOS apps

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I realize that iOS has the ability to have keyboard shortcuts (e.g.: Command-C for Copy, Command-V for Paste, etc). But is there a way to make your own keyboard shortcuts? Is there a way to implement them? I would like to know so that I can add them to some of my note-taking apps in the near-future. Thanks! :)

Comment: iOS doesn't do keyboard commands, silly!  You'll need to modify a UIMenuController.

Comment: It doesn't (natively)? I could've sworn it did! Ok, in regards to modifying a UIMenuController, how would the code look like?

Comment: Now that I won't give you!  We're a Q&A, not a for-hire group.  I can give you some resources though.

Comment: Ok. Sorry about that. Could you please recommend me some resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to modify a UIMenuController if you want to have your implementation blend in with the apple UI (It's always best to comply with the HIG!).  Here's the [class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Reference/UIMenuController_Class/UIMenuController.html), and a nice [tutorial](http://intridea.com/posts/developers-notes-for-uimenucontroller).